# Ошибка JS на Rails сервере

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails, vagrant

Запускаю сервер ruby on rais, заходит на login.html и выдает вот такую ошибку , 
[image: Ошибка rails&js]

Как ее можно исправить ? не меняя application на default ибо тогда пропадают все css стили, что мне не подходит.

Comment: Что даёт поиск "log2" по вашему css? Такое чувство, что у вас кусок js туда попал...

Comment: в application.css что, что подключено?

Comment: require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

//= require select2
//= require daterangepicker
//= require adminlte
//= require adminlte-blue
//= require datepicker3
//= require bootstrap-clockpicker
//= require main
//= require jquery.jcrop
//= require diffview
//= require ekko-lightbox

Comment: отключите (закомментируйте) по очереди каждую строку, и найдите, что вызывает ошибку

Comment: после нескольких перезагрузок сервера ошибка изменилась на конфликт версий плагина 'autoprefixer-rails' и node js .-.